# Canvas content would get cut off when I pass a very long path for `.clip()` operation

Tags: javascript, html, web, canvas, clip

I use `<canvas>` tag to draw some customized shapes, and everything goes well when I do normal drawing with Canvas's context operations.

The basic idea is to draw a very long round rectangle and then draw content inside it. In order to make the rectangle not covered by it's inside content, I clip the rectangle first, then draw content inside it.

The problem: if the height of rectangle is less than 18000px, everything's ok; once I set the height to some value that large than 18000px (the canvas itself is set to 20000px in my demo example), there will be an empty part in the bottom of this canvas, it seems part of content is cut off from canvas.

I put some thoughts below, but it's more clear to see the basic codes and my reproduced online demo, check it here https://bl.ocks.org/hijiangtao/4769c61573ebd2b068d6065930fbd65d (You can click the `open` link to open a new tab to see what is happening, or click https://bl.ocks.org/hijiangtao/raw/4769c61573ebd2b068d6065930fbd65d/ for result)

Here's my contructor:

```
constructor() {
    this.canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    this.canvas.width = 750;
    this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
}
```

Then I clip in this way (all my content drawing logic is inside `contentFn` function):

```
drawClipContent(
        x: number,
        y: number,
        width: number,
        height: number,
        radius?: number,
        contentFn?: Function
    ) {

        this.ctx.save();
        this.ctx.beginPath();

        this.ctx.translate(x, y);
        this.drawRoundRectPath(width, height, radius, true);
        this.ctx.clip();

        if (contentFn) {
            this.ctx.translate(-x, -y);
            contentFn();
        }

        this.ctx.closePath();
        this.ctx.restore();
    }
```

And here's my clip path Function `drawRoundRectPath`:

```
drawRoundRectPath(width: number, height: number, radius: number) {
        const topLeftRadius = radius;
        const topRightRadius = radius;
        const bottomLeftRadius = radius;
        const bottomRightRadius = radius;

        this.ctx.arc(width - bottomRightRadius, height - bottomRightRadius, bottomRightRadius, 0, Math.PI / 2);

        this.ctx.lineTo(bottomLeftRadius, height);

        this.ctx.arc(bottomLeftRadius, height - bottomLeftRadius, bottomLeftRadius, Math.PI / 2, Math.PI);

        this.ctx.lineTo(0, topLeftRadius);

        this.ctx.arc(topLeftRadius, topLeftRadius, topLeftRadius, Math.PI, (Math.PI * 3) / 2);

        this.ctx.lineTo(width - topRightRadius, 0);

        this.ctx.arc(width - topRightRadius, topRightRadius, topRightRadius, (Math.PI * 3) / 2, Math.PI * 2);

        this.ctx.lineTo(width, height - topRightRadius);
}
```

And there's one wired thing, which is all things goes well if I replace `this.drawRoundRectPath()` with just a calling of `this.ctx.rect()` with same shape.

The lost canvas looks like this (the Y axis of this part may goes about 18000px or so):

[image]

The expected canvas should shows a rectangle with round corner like this (the Y axis of this part may goes about 18000px or so):

[image]

The question is did I do something wrong in drawing canvas, or did my operation triggers some limit of canvas or some other mechanism of browsers? I am not sure, since everything goes fine if the height of rectangle is not too long.

Thx.

Comment: Does this happen on seceral browsers or just one?

Comment: @Kaiido I tried Chrome, Chrome Canary and Firefox with latest release version, however, I don't think it should be a problem of browsers internals, since what I searched shows the image still didn't reach the size limit of browsers themseleves.

Comment: Could you try to set up a [MCVE]? Could you at least show what `contentFn` does? [Here it works for me](https://jsfiddle.net/f2mxngq9/) drawing a simple rect.

Comment: @Kaiido Thx for reply, I just add an reproduced demo with https://bl.ocks.org/hijiangtao/4769c61573ebd2b068d6065930fbd65d

Comment: oO so your canvas is 20000px tall? Why didn't you say so?

Comment: @Kaiido I think it doesn't matter since all of them didn't reach the limit of canvas size itself. I should update it to problem description.

Comment: It does matter since your current description we were all assuming a 150px tall canvas, on which it does work as proven in my fiddle. And the issue is that you clip a shape bigger than 0x3fff (16bit). Not sure why it's clamped to 16bits though... The solution is to not draw that big at a time, but draw by smaller chunks.

Comment: @Kaiido Thx for pointing that. I am wondering what's the unit of 0x3fff (16bit), just in pixels? And is this limitation fits all other shapes' operation? Such as line, rectangle or so?

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216910/discussion-between-hijiangtao-and-kaiido

Comment: I don't know why StackOverflow's chat got 404 right now, there's one useful info about chromium at https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/graphics-and-skia

Answer (score 0):

I can not reproduce problem. But I suspect it could be some rounding errors that is causing the clip to fail.

You can try the following and remove all the calls to `ctx.lineTo` from the function `drawRoundRectPath`

It may or may not work. All the `lineTo` calls are adding path points very close to the start of the `arc`s You are defining two path points on top of each other. This should not cause a problem but as they are not needed to begin with, its worth a try.

```
drawRoundRectPath(width: number, height: number, radius: number) {
    this.ctx.arc(width - bottomRightRadius, height - bottomRightRadius, bottomRightRadius, 0, Math.PI / 2);
    this.ctx.arc(bottomLeftRadius, height - bottomLeftRadius, bottomLeftRadius, Math.PI / 2, Math.PI);
    this.ctx.arc(topLeftRadius, topLeftRadius, topLeftRadius, Math.PI, (Math.PI * 3) / 2);
    this.ctx.arc(width - topRightRadius, topRightRadius, topRightRadius, (Math.PI * 3) / 2, Math.PI * 2);
}
```

Comment: It also doesn't work. The question is it only cut off the bottom part of canvas in a very long rectangle `.clip()`, all things go normal when the height is set to some value smaller than 16000 or so. If the duplicated definition causes the problem, I think it would fail in all scenarios? I also tried just define four `lineTo()` and remove all `.arc()` callings (I think it equals to a normal `.rect()` in some aspect), but it failed either. :-(

Comment: By the way, I searched a lot but couldn't find a good way in debugging canvas in chrome,  so I can just print some states in console, but they are really the expected ones.

Comment: I added an online demo, just to reproduce the problem, as well as the codes https://bl.ocks.org/hijiangtao/4769c61573ebd2b068d6065930fbd65d

Comment: @hijiangtao I look at your online example and still could not reproduce the problem, this does look like a device dependent bug. To be sure its not a known problem in chrome go to chrome://gpu/ and it will give you a report on GPU status that may help.

Comment: Can you see a complete rectangle (with all four border radius displayed normally) inside the blue canvas background? The error is the clip path is cut off, so that you may see the top two borders with round effect, but bottom two without round effect, like the  first pic I paste in problem descriptions. And I think I found the reason with the help of @Kaiido, have a look at these https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216910/discussion-between-hijiangtao-and-kaiido

Comment: I think it shouldn't be a problem of specific device (browsers), since the implementations should be the same in one product, so I think you may misunderstood my problem limit to my descriptions?

Comment: @hijiangtao Yes I see the whole canvas with 4 rounded corners, I also injected some code and rendered content to the canvas using your clip to make sure what I was seeing was correct.

Comment: That's really wired, I had the problem in Chrome 83.0.4103.116 (macOS) and Chrome canary 86.0.4186.0 (macOS), they are all the latest versions, is it because you are using  Linux, Windows or some other OS?

Comment: I may save demo codes by accident, and change the height to a normal range, you can try to set height of rectangle to a value large than 16383px, I set it as 18000px, then you will see the problem. I revised it https://gist.github.com/hijiangtao/4769c61573ebd2b068d6065930fbd65d/revisions